# Spring Expression language - map values based on url (based on the path without host and port)

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

I am trying to map a value in SpEL (Spring Expression Language).

I need to map certain values based on the url path

```
https://www1.qa4.testsite.com/sso-login : External
https://www1.qa4.testsite.com/www : Normal
https://www.testsite.com/main/personal : Marketing
```

What would be the expression to achieve this value other than checking the whole string value. Need expression to check only the path ('sso-logn' , 'www' , 'main/personal')

`#map(#requestInfo.httpReferer,  {'https://www1.qa4.testsite.com/sso-login': 'External', 'https://www.testsite.com/main/personal': 'Marketing', 'https://www1.qa4.testsite.com/www': 'Normal'}, 'Normal')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a working expression

```
#map(#requestInfo?.httpReferer?.split("m/")?.$[true], {'sso-login': 'External', 'www': 'Marketing', 'main/personal': 'Normal'}, 'Normal')
```